# Windows does not recognize partition

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I used gparted to resize two partitions on a Windows XP machine, however something went wrong, and now Windows can not recognize the partition format of the first partition (the one containing Windows), however it boots fine, and I am able to browse the data on the partition, and it seems to have the right size as well. However I fear that sooner or later this will result in some nasty problems and possibly data loss.

Is there a simple way to recover from these problems, and leave the computer in a more stable state? I am looking for some kind of tool that can recover the partition.

Comment: You should probably use SuperUser for this instead of SO.

Comment: Yeah, just realised that, I see there is a migrate function available, but can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to apply the latest service pack for Windows XP.  You are probably using a later version of the filesystem on the other partition.

Comment: That could very well be, I will give it a shot tomorrow, when I see it, its a family members computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall the computer and repartition it during installation.
Never use a non-stable computer if a data lose occur - it doesn't the worth the time it take to install a new machine now...

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup everything
2. Test the backup works!
3. Copy the backup somewhere
4. Test the second backup worked!
5. Re-partition & Reformat
6. Recover the backup